# Multiple await when iterating an array in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have an N:M relation between two tables in MongoDB called X and Y. Both tables have records in them. I need to update these two tables with relations to each other. I do this by importing a file with relations. I need to do this synchronously in the following logical order:

1. find record in X to get internal id X-1
2. find and update record in Y to point to X-1
3. update record in X to point to Y1

Three operations would give me a N:N relation between X1 and Y1.

The problem is that when I iterate over the array calling these three operations synchronously, it doesn't work because the execution of the loop does not wait for the promises.

Here's my pseudo-code:

```
let relations = JSON.parse(data);
productsRelations.map(async (relation) => {
  let x1 = await findX(x1); // find x1 based on info in file
  let y1 = await findAndUpdateY(y1, x1); // find and update y1 with relation to x1
  await updateX(x1, y1); // update x1 with relation to y1
});
```

Result is that `findX` is not yet resolved when `findAndUpdateY` is called. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this I hope someone can enlighten me with.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since `findX` is `await`ed, this should guarantee that it's resolved by the time `findAndUpdateY` is called, so the explanation and the code don't make sense to me. Also, while it's nice to provide a [mcve], obfuscating the question with `X` and `Y` might be removing too much information and context. See [what is the x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (which is a conceptual phenomenon unrelated to the names you picked).

Comment: If you have a map of operations, where each operation depends on the previous operation, why would you write that as an async map? `async` functions run synchronously _until they hit an `await`_ so by trying to make async code synchronous, you've actually made the map itself a giant parallel operation.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, that solved it. I added my solution to the original question. I don't know how I was thinking about the async map. I did try without the async keyword but the obviously could not use the await keyword. Although it now works, I'm still not comfortable enough to say I fully understand but hopefully getting there in the end

Comment: Don't edit your solution into your question. SO is a question and answer site: post your solution as an answer, and then accept that.

Comment: Solution added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reply from @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans was indeed the issue. I changed it to this to get the expected result:

```
const updateRelations = async (relation) => {
  let x1 = await findX(x1);
  let y1 = await findAndUpdateY(y1, x1);
}
let relations = JSON.parse(data);
for (const relation of relations) {
  await updateRelations(relation);
}
```